# can i fetch the xaml button style on my dynamic button?

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem i have some dynamic button and i want to put some style on it
like my other button(Xaml button).how can i fetch the xaml code using c#? but it gives N ERROR

```
 buttonlanguage.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("Glassbutton");
```

Comment: Hi SHASHANK, I've seen several of your questions come by that indicate you are constructing buttons in code rather than doing them the proper WPF way.  Every time I see this I cringe:  All the difficulties you are encountering would melt away if you were to use ItemsControl the way it was intended to be used rather than doing a "foreach" loop.  I feel like you are wasting time learning to do things the backwards way, and even though I don't know you I hate to see you do it.  I suggest you take a week off and look at some good MVVM-based example applications to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your style in the resources section in xaml and call from code-behind like this:

```
myDynamicButton.Style = (Style)myWindow.FindResource("myButtonStyle");
```

Comment: but it give en error on mywindow content i put here my  windowform name?

Comment: Glassbutton Resourse not found-- but i put it in resourse

Comment: in xaml i also used resoursefile

Comment: there is aneed to give the key for this

Comment: @SHASHANK: `Glassbutton` should be the key. By the way, where have you defined all the styles. In resource dictionary(separate file) or application.resources/windows.resources(embedded)?

Comment: @SHASHANK: if it is a resourcedictionary you can retrieve it by instantiating ResourceDictionary, setting its source and accessing it like this: `buttonlanguage.Style = (style)myResDic["Glassbutton"];`